# More efficient nested loops calculation

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nested-loops

Is there a way I can make the below activity more efficient.

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)sortArrayOfOrdersByDate:(NSMutableArray *)array{

    //create an array of the dates from the Order class
    NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (Order *order in array)
        [dates addObject:[Utility parseDateFromString:order.date format:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"]];

    //algorithm to sort the array of dates
    NSArray *datesSorted = [dates sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
        ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
             return [obj2 compare:obj1];
        }];

    //match and build a complete, sorted array of orders
    NSMutableArray *ordersSorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSDate *theDate in datesSorted)
        for (Order *order in array)
            if ([[Utility parseStringFromDate:theDate format:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"] isEqualToString:order.date])
                [ordersSorted addObject:order];

    return ordersSorted;
}
```

I'll explain what's going on, I have a class called Order which is pulled from the database.
As the database is SQLite which doesn't support datetime fields, there's no easy way for me to sort by date from within my query, which is how I came about writing this function.

Order has a property 'date', which is just a string of text.
For this, I'm creating an array of NSDates using a date-parsed version of this value.

I sort the dates, and then try to make a new array by comparing a string-parsed version of each date, with what's stored in order.date

I have about 80 orders in my test database, and there's a noticeable delay on tapping the button that opens the viewcontroller.

Can anybody help make this more efficient, I understand it's pretty hacky at present?

**OUTCOME**

With @bbum's advice, I parsed and stored the `order.date` property as an `NSDate` when it comes out of the database, then used a simple `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` call which allows easy comparison between the `order.date` properties.

See below for the solution:

```
+ (NSArray *)sortArrayOfOrdersByDate:(NSMutableArray *)array{
    return [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
        return [((Order *)obj2).date compare:((Order *)obj1).date];
    }];
}
```

Absence of Parsing/Unparsing makes this solution much faster, also, I managed to cut out the double loop and the single loop above it.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but why do you not add an ORDER BY clause to the query pulling from the database?

Comment: @bengoesboom SQLite doesn't support datetime fields, so ordering by the date field would treat it as a string. In the required date format, there are likely to be inconsistencies because the dates are not hierarchical (yyyy-mm-dd), instead they are american (mm-dd-yyyy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to represent the date in SQLITE in a sortable format;  # of seconds since epoch is typical.   Then you can use an ORDER BY as @bengoesboom suggested.

If you can't do that, then you can collapse those two loops into  a single call to `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` where the comparator does the conversion.

That, of course, is going to be really slow because you'll be repeatedly parsing the dates.  You *really* need to represent the dates in the objects as `NSDates`, probably by doing the conversion when fetched from the database.

And, of course, I hope you are at least using something like FMDB and not the raw SQLite APIs.   As well, if you don't need data format portability, consider using Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using FMDB, yeah - Thanks for your help, I think it'll be much more efficient if I store the data property as an NSDate instead of a string, as you suggest, I'll make this adjustment then look into improving the loops! If I can cut out the parsing dates then I can effectively cut the delay. I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks for your help @bbum, I updated the question to include my resultant solution, which is much more efficient (and less lines!), thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

A. If you control the format of records in the database and wish to store the dates as strings (as opposed to numbers) then store them in the string format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. Such dates remain human-readable and also sort correctly as strings. You can now use an SQL query to extract your records sorted.

B. If you can't control the format as above then you can improve the algorithm.

You could consider sorting an array of orders directly, but if you do that you will be converting strings to dates multiple times and the cost of this might be high.

Another option is to create an array of {date, order} pairs, sort that array by date, the first element of the pair, and then your orders, the second element of the pair are in the correct order. You can then unzip the pairs and make an array of sorted orders. To do this you'll need to define a class for the pairs etc.

A third option, and maybe the best combination of speedup/ease is to replace the pairs above by an array of dates and a dictionary of date -> orders. Dictionary are based on hashing - O(1) - so are fast. The outline to do this is (i.e. code not tested):

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)sortArrayOfOrdersByDate:(NSMutableArray *)array
{

    //create an array of the dates from the Order class
    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray new];
    NSMutableDictionary *dateToOrder = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    for (Order *order in array)
    {
        NSDate *orderDate = [Utility parseDateFromString:order.date format:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
        [dates addObject:orderdate];
        [dateToOrder addObject:order forKey:orderDate];
    }

    //algorithm to sort the array of dates
    NSArray *datesSorted = [dates sortedArrayUsingComparator: 
        ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
             return [obj2 compare:obj1];
        }];

    // O(n) extraction of sorted orders
    // notFoundMarker unused as dates only contains keys in the dictionary
    NSArray *ordersSorted = [dateToOrder objectsForKeys:dates notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];

    return ordersSorted;
}
```